# How to inspect the format of a file on HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Give an HDFS path, how to figure out what format it is (text, sequence or parquet)?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's not easy to accomplish your demand, unless all your files inside HDFS follow some conventions, e.g. `.txt` for text, `.seq` fro sequence and `.parquet` for parquet file.

However, you could check your file manually using `cat`.

- HDFS cat: `hadoop dfs -cat /path/to/file | head` to check if it's a text file.
- [Parquet head](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools):  parquet-tools head [option...] /path/to/file
- or, write a program to read....

Answer (score 3):

use "hdfs dfs -cat /path/to/file | head ",

1) for orc file, the command can print the "ORC" flag in the first line

2) for parquet file, the command can print the "PAR1" flag in the first line

3) for text file, the command can print the all the content of file

Answer (score 1):

String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension("hdfs://path-to-file");
Working with Hadoop 2.5.2

Comment: What if the file doesn't have any extension? Will this work?